# How can I get the href value from a link?

Tags: theming, 10

I have a link I render in a template file with the following markup.

```
{{ item.caption.link }}
```

I want to show only the `href` value. None of the following worked for me.

```
{{ item.caption.link[0]['#url'] }}
{{ item.caption.link.0.url }}
{{ item.caption.link[0]['#url']|render }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be better if you pass just href value as a variable to Twig and not the complete HTML markup.

Put HTML in Twig and just fill it with the values (href value in that case) you need.

Comment: This is generated dynamic by a module and I am override the twig template in theme

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what this variable holds. Can you inspect it with Xdebug or sth?

Answer (score 0):

First look for the available attributes with [this tutorial on XDebug](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates#s-viewing-variables).

Another method to inspect a variable is to  use the `dd()` function. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73216680/drupal-9-dd-ddm-or-drupal-dump-missing) to install it.
Put the following in your template, it will print all the available attributes of your link :

```
{{ dd(item.caption.link) }}
```

Try the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499554/extract-url-title-from-link-field-in-drupal-8) :

```
{{ item.caption.link.0['#url'] }}
```

If this doesn't work, you should access at least to the `uri`. See this question to [get an URL from the URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56057060/drupal-links-showing-internal-and-entity/75337997#75337997).